# Calculate new Average by using old AverageRating and New Value

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I am implementing a rating system in asp.net. I have a table for Rating. The structure of Rating table is simple,

Table Name: Rating

```
Id      ProductId      RatingValue
1          1                3.5
2          1                3.0
3          1                2.5
4          2                4.0
```

Now while selecting data from sql table I use built in AVG function,

```
ISNULL(AVG([Rating].[RatingValue]), 0)
```

This work fine. Now when the user rate the same product again in the database then I have to insert the new rating in the Sql table "Rating" and have to update the label control with the new average rating. I can do this by using a select statement after saving the record in the database table but this will an extra round trip to the database. Now I have Old AverageRating value and the number of times the product is rated.

I now have two options.

Option 1: Either somehow return the new AverageValue from within the Insert Statement (I could select identity column but don't know whether I could select Average of column or not)

Option 2: Use the old AverageRating and CountRated values in application. I can use the new value of rating with these values to calculate the new value at runtime.

Which option is best and how to achieve them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `CountRated` is the number of times the product is rated, before the new value of `RatingValue` :

```
AverageRating = (AverageRating * CountRated + RatingValue) / (CountRated + 1);
```

It can be faster than recalculating average from all data, but it may be less accurate with lot of data.

Comment: Thanks @Xaruth. It has solved my problem. I have to just put a check if the rating is for the first time then show the original RatingValue in the label otherwise I use your formula. Because if the rating is for the first time then CountRated and AverageRating values are 0.

Comment: I think you don't need, because the first time will be : `(0*0+ RatingValue)/(0+1)`. So the first time, AverageRating = RatingValue.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. Actually I was incrementing RatingValue for a different purpose before that. RatingCount++